# Process output stream stuck on read even though process writes to console

Tags: c#

Code snippet:

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\KataGo\\katago.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "gtp";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.Start();

        StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;

        Console.WriteLine("A");
        reader.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("B");
```

Output:

```
        A
        KataGo v1.11.0
        ...
```

KataGo by itself uses a console to synchronously interact. It prints info at the start, then waits for a command, gives output, waits again etc.

The "A" indicates that my program starts reading before the program starts outputting. Yet it doesn't output "B" until I manually stop the program and the process is discarded. So it waits for something to read but doesn't get anything even though there are things getting written.

The same behavior occurs with reader.ReadLine() and reader.ReadToEnd().
Using process.OutputDataReceived and process.BeginOutputReadLine() instead also doesn't catch anything.

The only reason I can think of is that the console (it's a normal C# Console Application) reads everything before my stream does. But I don't know how to have the process use a custom stream instead of the standard to test it.

I also tried process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; and it doesn't output to the console. But reader.Read() still gets stuck, so I guess it breaks the executable.

Comment: Perhaps the executable writes its banner/version to stderr? Try setting         `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;` and then read from `process.StandardError`

Comment: That was it, thanks! Didn't even think to test it because it worked with the normal output stream in Java. But I guess the Java ProcessBuilder combines out and err.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mathias, The outside program wrote to StandardError.

Comment: Can't accept my own answer ._.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).